# Can't ask question on Arqade because I've asked too many recently

Tags: support, asking-questions, rate-limiting

I've just recently posted a question on Arqade, and I was going to post another one about a separate topic, when I got a message that I've "asked 2 questions recently." The last time I asked another question anywhere on Stack Exchange before the one on Arqade was in November 21. Why am I being limited even though I have not asked multiple questions on Arqade recently?

This isn't a long-term ban, it is just for 2 days because it thinks I have posted too much too recently or something.

Comment: Have you asked and deleted a question anywhere on the network in the last day or two? How long was it between questions on Arqade? I think there's a 40 minute cool down for low-reputation users.

Comment: To those who think this is a duplicate: I can post again in 2 days, so it's not a long-term ban. I The last time other than today that I've posted something on Arquade was in November, @Catija

Comment: No, the 40 minute limit is network wide.

Comment: Are you able to post on [meta.gaming.se]? That might be a better place for this question, if so (main meta can unfortunately be quite a harsh environment for people who aren't familiar with it).

Comment: What about migrating this to Arqade Meta?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Alright, checking things out (I'm one of the Arqade mods) - looks like [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/asking-rate-limited) applies to you. You've run into the rate limit because your questions haven't been super well received (we don't get exact details, but I can see that there's not a lot of positive votes on them, for example).

I think the thing that caught you specifically today was a question of yours got deleted in an automatic clean up process (specifically the one [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/78048/enable-automatic-deletion-of-old-unanswered-zero-score-questions-after-a-year/92006#92006) that mentions "RemovedAbandonedClosed"). That, added to the other issues with your other questions being poorly received is what likely landed you with the 2 day rate limit.

Comment: Yes, now I remember posting a question a while ago that was deleted, but I think I posted it weeks ago...